# How many poor numbers are there?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, algebraic-number-theory, factorial

> A number $n$ is called *poor* if there does not exist a positive integer $m$ such that $m!$ has exactly $n$ trailing zeros. How many *poor* numbers are less than or equal to $2018$?

The question is from annual city math contest $2018$. I have made the following progress to solve the problem:

It is known that $m!$ has $Z=\lfloor\frac m5\rfloor+\lfloor\frac m{25}\rfloor+\dots$ trailing zeros. If $m$ is divisible by $5$, all the numbers $m!$, $(m+1)!$, $(m+2)!$, $(m+3)!$, $(m+4)!$ has the same number of trailing zeros. So, we take only the $m$s that are divisible by $5$.

$m!$ has $4$ trailing zeros for $m=24$. But $25!$ has $6$ trailing zeros. Since $Z$ is always increasing (not necessarily strict), we get that $5$ is a *poor* number. This happens for all multiples of $25$ i.e a number is skipped skipped from the value of $Z$ and the skipped number is always a *poor* one. Similarly, two numbers are skipped for the multiples of $125$. More generally, if $m$ is a multiple of $5^k$, $k-1$ numbers get skipped from the values of $Z$ or equivalently we get $k-1$ poor numbers for each such $m$.

Now based on the observations above, I calculated first few *poor* numbers. They are: $$5,11,17,23,29,30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 61,\dots $$
The sequence is quite interesting and matches with [A000966](https://oeis.org/A000966). However, I am unable to find the number of *poor* numbers that are less than or equal to $2018$.

Comment: Just count them.

Comment: The result is basically the count of numbers $x$ such that $25\mid x$ + the count $125\mid x$ + $625\mid x$ such that $x\leq 2018$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There is a strictly increasing bijection between non-poor numbers and multiples of 5.

> So, find the least $k$ such that $(5k)!$ has at least 2018 zeros, and your answer will be $2018 - k$.